# Alternative to getKeys() of phpredis

Tags: php, logging, redis, deprecated

My phpErrorLog tells me that `getKeys()` is deprecated.

```bsh
[01-Oct-2020 16:44:02 Europe/Berlin] PHP Deprecated: Function Redis::getKeys() is deprecated in <pathToFile> on line xxx
```

I wonder what the alternative to getKeys is. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything there on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `keys` to resolve the issue. The documentation notes that `getKeys` is an alias for `keys` and will be removed in future versions of phpredis.

Reference: https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/148bf373b7a0d276f6f6fd1ec1e6b9407fba6497/README.markdown#keys-getkeys

Comment: > The documentation notes that getKeys is an alias for keys and will be removed in future versions of phpredis.

I actually missed that. thanks @jasonandmonte !